# how to revert one latest cherry-pick and retain others on local copy?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

**current state:**
*I have a checkout version, on top of which, I have cherry picked various other commits (lets say 4-5 commits), which are some fixes.

Now, I have to validate other fix without loosing my last working state. I therefore have cherry picked a commit-id (let us say `X`). And after my validation, I would just want to undo commit-id-X cherry-pick, but other cherry picks should stay intact.*

Please suggest, if Git supports some command to do this job directly.

Comment: `git reset HEAD^ --hard` to move your current branch back to the previous commit.

Comment: but i had been applying my cherry-picks with --no-commit option. And now, if I  reset --hard, will it not reset everything?

Comment: I checked the log history, and then I could see all the cherry-picked commits in there. Since, my last cherry-pick was the one, that I wanted to ditch. I did `git reset --soft HEAD~`. And hence, only the last cherry-pick (local commit) was discarded, and rest all intact.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo a successful "git cherry-pick"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986376/how-to-undo-a-successful-git-cherry-pick)

Answer (score 0):

> but I had been applying my cherry-picks with `--no-commit` option

Then you can revert with the same option the commit X previously cherry-picked:

```
git revert --no-commit X
```

[`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) will reverse the effect of commit `X` (and only `X`), and the `--no-commit` option will allow to apply the changes necessary to revert the named commit to the working tree and the index, but does not make the commit.